# Provide data to highcharts from a Java method

Tags: java, arrays, list, highcharts

I have a java method which retrieves data from database and a bean which manages this data.

Using **Arrays.toString(var)**, I get this array `[{'tom','1'},{'sawyer','2'}]` but highcharts accept data only in this format `['tom','1','sawyer','2']`

For now I have to get the array and using replace function to get the correct format but all this has to be done manually.

My question is how to convert the array to the correct format and then pass it to the highcharts data.

1. How to load a Java method on page load?

Thank you for your patience and help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data that needs to be passed to highcharts must be JSON. So the best way to do this is to use a JSON library. http://json.org/java/

Comment: the array is still printed as the incorrect format.. In JSF, the curly brackets give errors and thus the chart isnt even displayed!

Answer (score 0):

Data can be passed also using xml.. The best way to pass data i found is to create a string tn the java class by itself and in the page calling this java method we just need to create an xml dom parser which will convert the string to xml and thus push data to highcharts using jQuery easily.